# Can i Pass Id and specific column name in Laravel URL Parameter?

Tags: laravel, url, frameworks, php-7, laravel-7

I want to receive from URL id or column name and then get results by these parameters.

Something like this Route::get('orders/classifier/{id_or_name}', 'ClassifierController@show')->name('get_classifier');

{id_or_name} - it's example. Here I want to get id one time and name another time. Next, I want to use it from getting data from the database.

And next in method:

Classifier::whereName($id_or_name)->orWhere('id', $id_or_name)->get();

It is possible in Laravel?

Comment: Use a if statement where you check if $id_or_name is a integer instead of whereRelationName and orWhere. you cannot do that in one simple query

Comment: Thanks! Yes, you're right. I refactored my code

Answer (score -1):

Yes. It is possible. By URL parameters i can get any information in integer or string types.